# Cplex 5002 error on my expression

Tags: expression, cplex

I'm new to Cplex and opl but trying to do my project with this.

I just finished my source but it won't work.

Googled and tried to get a solution for this but I failed to make it work.

What I understand now is something's wrong with my expression.

```
maximize C_vehicle * (k - sum(k in bus) y[k]) + 
C_fuel * (T - sum(i in school_and_student, j in school_and_student, k in bus) 
t[i][j] * x[i][j][k]);'
```

I think I should divide it into several parts but I'm not sure and don't know how.

I was wondering anyone could give me an idea on this?

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: Give us a bit more info - what in your expression are the constants and the variables, and what was the error message? Have you tried breaking it down into smaller and simpler parts?

Comment: Same question at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=51c0de53-da84-4f83-bb5c-c3d6ac8db878&ps=25